# Can Aesop's Pawnshop Remove Wyldside before the start-of-turn resolves?

Tags: android-netrunner

> ### [Aesop's Pawnshop](http://netrunner.randomblink.com/coreset/aesopspawnshop)
>
> When your turn begins, you may trash another of your installed cards to gain 3 [**credits**].

---

> ### [Wyldside](http://netrunner.randomblink.com/coreset/wyldside)
>
> When your turn begins, draw 2 cards and lose [**click**] .

**Questions:**

1. If I wish to use **Aesop's Pawnshop** to `trash` **Wyldside**, which one happens first?
2. Could you stop **Wyldside** from activating it's `start of turn` action by **Aesop's Pawnshop** -ping it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You choose the order they resolve.**

If Wyldside resolves first:

1. Draw two cards, lose a click
2. Sell Wyldside with Aesop's: trash it and gain three credits

Or, if Aesop's resolve first:

1. Sell Wyldside for three credits
2. Wyldside does nothing because it's been trashed (so you keep all four clicks)

This specific scenario is actually covered in the rulebook ([PDF](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/ADN01_Rules_ENG_Lo-Res.pdf)) on page 22, under "Simultaneous Effect Example":

> The Runner has Aesop’s Pawnshop and Wyldside installed and both have the same trigger condition of “When your turn begins.” The Runner begins his turn and can choose to trigger the optional conditional ability on Aesop’s Pawnshop first, gaining 3 [Credits] by trashing Wyldside. This stops Wyldside’s required conditional ability from triggering, keeping the Runner from losing [Click].

Comment: Ouch. I need to re-read the rule-book. I'm an old-school Netrunner... still have the old cards in my brain so I don't think to read the rule-book except for stuff that wasn't in the old system like influence and such.

Comment: @randomblink No worries! There are actually loads of timing-related questions like that around the game. Glad I could help and welcome to the site!

Comment: So... I'm new to stackexchange (ok, like 2-3 weeks new) and I'm madly in love. Why isn't there an android-netrunner.stackexchange.com? Is there an answer for that?

Comment: @randomblink: Because there aren't *enough* questions for it. We have Magic: The Gathering questions here (lots of them!), and even they don't have their own site. B&CG is still in "beta" status, after a few years, because we don't have enough activity to justify leaving beta. So keep asking Android: Netrunner questions, and answering when you can.